# How to only add common index pandas data frame?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Suppose I have two data frame. I would like to add both values if there is a common index otherwise take the value. Let me illustrate this with an example

```
import pandas as pd

In [118]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4], index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=4))

In [119]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(10*np.ones_like(df1.values[1:3]), index=df1.index[1:3])

In [120]: df1.add(df2)
Out[120]: 
               0
2018-01-01   NaN
2018-01-02  12.0
2018-01-03  13.0
2018-01-04   NaN
```

However, I wanted to get

```
               0
2018-01-01   1.0
2018-01-02  12.0
2018-01-03  13.0
2018-01-04   4.0
```

How can I achieve this? Moreover, is it even possible if `df2.index` is not a proper subset of `df1.index`, i.e. if

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(10*np.ones_like(df1.values[1:3]), index=pd.DatetimeIndex([df1.index[1], pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')]))

In [131]: df2
Out[131]: 
             0
2018-01-02  10
2019-01-01  10

In [132]: df1.add(df2)
Out[132]: 
               0
2018-01-01   NaN
2018-01-02  12.0
2018-01-03   NaN
2018-01-04   NaN
2019-01-01   NaN
```

But what I wanted is

```
               0
2018-01-01   1.0
2018-01-02  12.0
2018-01-03   3.0
2018-01-04   4.0
2019-01-01  10.0
```

Comment: `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine with `fillna`

```
df1.add(df2).fillna(df1)
Out[581]: 
               0
2018-01-01   1.0
2018-01-02  12.0
2018-01-03  13.0
2018-01-04   4.0
```

Ok,

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).sum(level=0)
Out[591]: 
             0
2018-01-01   1
2018-01-02  12
2018-01-03   3
2018-01-04   4
2019-01-01  10
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. What if `df2.index` is not a proper subset of the `df1.index`

Comment: @math Update, and I think this one will create less confusion by using pd.concate